# Source code usage/include scheme generator

Tags: c, linux

I'm looking for a tool that will let me see some kind of a global scheme of the usage of include in the entire project. Something like this: [image]

How was this image generated?

PS: I'm sorry if this is not the right place to ask or if I tagged the question wrongly. I'm not sure what tags should I use.

Comment: you can read about the program named `dot` (graphviz)

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Do you have a link? Searching for ```dot``` in Google is returning too much noise

Comment: http://www.graphviz.org/

Comment: From what I see, this will only allow me do draw the actual data, but it won't scan my project. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Graphviz will not do the "project scanning", only the graphics. Where did you find your image?

Comment: Maybe you could run the C preprocessor and dig the graph out of the '# filename linenumber' lines.

Comment: @CharlieBurns I found that image somewhere in google images, couldn't relate it to any project

Comment: "but it won't scan my project" => dot/graphviz plugins should exist for IDE as Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

This is [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) generated graph, it uses [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) as diagram generator. You need to install Doxygen and GraphViz and you can follow the steps in this [page](http://masterravi.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/dependency-graph/) if you are interested in the headers.

Comment: The thing is that I really don't need/want all that webpage-base docs that doxygen generates. I just want a few pics showing how my files include each other.